# multiple UNWIND handling empty lists

Tags: neo4j, cypher

I want to add a node `Paper` and unwind 2 lists `a` and `t` (if they are not empty), create a relation (HAS_WRITTEN or HAS_KEYWORD) each element of each list.
I get the error `expected whitespace or a relationship pattern` on `MERGE (author:Author { name: a.name })`. My usage of UNWIND with CASE is pretty similar to the one in [docs](https://neo4j.com/docs/developer-manual/current/cypher/clauses/unwind/#unwind-using-unwind-with-an-empty-list)

```
MERGE (n:Paper {name: "mystuff"})
WITH n,[{name:"john"}] AS a, [{name:"computer_stuff"}] AS t
UNWIND 
   CASE
      WHEN a = []
         THEN [null]
      ELSE 
          MERGE (author:Author { name: a.name })
          MERGE (author)-[:HAS_WRITTEN]->(n)
   END
WITH a
UNWIND 
   CASE
       WHEN t = [] THEN [null]
      ELSE 
          MERGE (topic:Topic { name: t.name })
          MERGE (n)-[:HAS_KEYWORD]->(topic)
   END
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`MERGE` is an operation (not a function) and it does not *return a value*. Therefore, it cannot be used inside a `CASE` clause.

This query should do what you want:

```
WITH [{name:"john"}] AS authors, [{name:"computer_stuff"}] AS topics
MERGE (n:Paper {name: "mystuff"})
FOREACH(a IN authors |
  MERGE (author:Author { name: a.name })
  MERGE (author)-[:HAS_WRITTEN]->(n))
FOREACH(t IN topics |
  MERGE (topic:Topic { name: t.name })
  MERGE (n)-[:HAS_KEYWORD]->(topic))
```

Comment: do you think there is no way to avoid FOREACH?

Comment: thanks, but I use CASE for avoid UNWIND on empty list [docs](https://neo4j.com/docs/developer-manual/current/cypher/clauses/unwind/#unwind-using-unwind-with-an-empty-list). In case "authors" or "topics" are empty your query will have unexected results

Comment: I restored my original answer. There should be ways to avoid using `FOREACH`, but they would all probably be more complex. Why do you want to avoid `FOREACH`? It seems perfectly suited for your use case.

Comment: However, if you really need to avoid `FOREACH`, you can look at [apoc.do.case](https://neo4j-contrib.github.io/neo4j-apoc-procedures/#_case_procedures).

Answer (score 0):

You can't use MERGE in an UNWIND CASE statement.

Think of UNWIND CASE like a switch statement where you are selecting a value to use for the UNWIND part. MERGE is not a list or null, so it is not a valid value.